# MATLAB function arguments in my code

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB code and I do how understand how it works.In the main code

```
%Tuning
tunestruct = {samplefunc,numreps,data_type,MS_criterion};
[Xtrain,optk,optsig2,tuningExtras] = tuneSKSC(data,kernel_type,maxk,tunestruct);
```

tuneSKC.m starts with

```
function [Xtrain,optk,optsig2,extras] = tuneSKSC(datastruct,kernel,maxk,tunestruct)
```

My question is what is `tunestruct`?Then, are `data,kernel_type,maxk,tunestruct arguments` for function?

I have pasted tunestruct.m 
http://pastebin.com/cFH433Md

Comment: Yes those are all arguments to the function. As far as *what* they are, you will need to ask the author. All that you can infer is that `tunestruct` is a cell array of `{samplefunc,numreps,data_type,MS_criterion}`

Comment: @Suever Thanks,why is the author using cell array instead of single arguments?

Comment: You must ask the author, but one reason could be to gather all information about an object in one variable. It makes it much easier to pass information around, as you can use only `tunestruct` instead of `samplefunc, numreps, data_type, MS_criterion`. You can also use structs for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tunestruct` is actually a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) made of a bunch of other variables.

> A cell array is a data type with indexed data containers called cells, where each cell can contain any type of data. Cell arrays commonly contain either lists of text strings, combinations of text and numbers, or numeric arrays of different sizes.

The reason of making a cell array instead of passing those arguments as separate values each times, is that the code has a very specific pattern for handling this set of parameters, in case they are not passed as arguments, as described in this code segment you've provided:

```
if exist('tunestruct','var')
    if ~iscell(tunestruct)
        tunestruct = {tunestruct,1};    
    end;

    if(strcmp(tunestruct{1},'furs'))
    tunestruct{2} = 1; %furs is deterministic, only one repetition is enough
    end

    s1 = ~strcmp(tunestruct{3},'net_unw') && strcmp(tunestruct{4},'Modularity');
    if(s1)
    tunestruct{4} = 'AMS';  %Modularity is used for unweighted network data
    warning('\nNot possible to use Modularity, using AMS instead...');
    end

end;
```

Comment: What makes you think it's a `struct`? Looks like a cell array to me.

Comment: That's actually what I meant and there this line `if ~iscell(tunestruct)` in the code segment I have posted. I am sorry for this silly mistake.